# Matching 'n' Locks with 'n' keys

Tags: arrays, algorithm

There are n identical-looking locks and n distinct keys. Each lock can be opened only with one key out of the given keys. Match each lock-key pair.

I have solved this problem with a brute force approach O(n^2) but I want to know if there is an efficient solution to this problem.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted your code

Comment: Is there any other way of finding out which key opens which lock apart from trying it? And should you optimise for the number of lock-key attempts?

Comment: @biziclop No, we can find if a key fits in the lock only by trying it. We want to minimise number of attempts required for matching all locks with keys.

Comment: Also, as I wrote the question myself while trying to find variations of nuts and bolts problem, edits and suggestions in the problem are welcome.

Comment: In that case I don't see anything better than `n+(n-1)+(n-2)...+1` attempts, which is O(n^2). The reason being is that you've got to try `n` locks to match the first key, but the only information from that step you can transfer to the second key is that you don't need to try the lock the first key already opened.

Comment: How do you know whether a key fits in a lock?

Comment: In the original "nuts and bolts" problem each fitting operation tells _either the nut is bigger than the bolt; the bolt is bigger than the nut; or they are
the same size (and so fit together)_. This is more information than just "fit" or "doesn't fit". So, which case are you investigating?

Comment: @BagdanGilevich Actually I hadn't fully understood the nuts and bolts problem at the time of writing this problem so I tried to break the nuts and bolts problem into a simpler one. Here I was investigating this exact case that what happens when we can only test "fit" or "doesn't fit" in a trial. Turned out that the efficient quicksort solution of original problem exists only because of extra information of smaller or greater size in a comparison.

Answer (score -2):

Please check if this can help-

1) 
Quick Sort Way Θ(nlogn): a quick sort technique can be applied to solve.

The problem can be reduced to nuts and bolts for understanding the logic.

// Choose pivot (can be last or any element) to partition.
            pivot = partition(locks, low, high, keys_pivot);

```
        // Now use returned pivot to partition keys - 
        // As key/lock should be at same index
        partition(keys, low, high, locks_pivot[pivot]);

        matchPairs(keys, locks, low, pivot-1);
        matchPairs(keys, locks, pivot+1, high);
```

Example, 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/nuts-bolts-problem-lock-key-problem/

2) Hash function O(n):

```
 Add all locks to HashMap<> / plain array
 Iterate over keys to find a matching pair
```

Example,
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/nuts-bolts-problem-lock-key-problem-set-2-hashmap/

Comment: The problem as currently described by OP is substantially different from the "nuts and bolts problem" you are referring to. For example there is no larger-smaller relation between keys and locks. There is also no natural order between locks or keys.

Comment: Note that these only work if the locks/keys expose some sort of id value that matches up. If the only available operation is to test whether a given key matches a given lock, you've got no other option than to try all `n*(n-1)/2` combinations.